# Virtual box making filesystem unwritable in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive

When i open virtual box and select a iso disk from a internal harddrive, all partions on the harddrive become unwritable. This issue exists even after restarting the system. Can anyone tell me a solution? This is happening with all virtualisation software installed on my system. There is no problem when working with drive where os is installed or external hard drive.

My host is Ubuntu 22.04, and it is installed on my computer. I was trying virtual box on my computer, and the error appeared when I opened the file selector to select my iso from my internal drive. I did not mount any os or iso in my vm.

Comment: It's not clear to me what OS/release you're using as both *host* or *VM*.  Is the 22.04 mentioned in your title the HOST OS? or the *VM*? or both?  Is your OS installed? or *live* (thus RO is expected), and its common for VMs to not see any HOST drive/partitions but only what the HOST OS defined them to see (*which maybe RO for numerous reasons*).  Providing clear details may help people like me understand what you're asking, thus your issue.

Comment: My host is Ubuntu 22.04, and it is installed on my computer. I was trying virtual box on my computer, and the error appeared when I opened the file selector to select my iso from my internal drive. I did not mount any os or iso in my vm.